# Pass instance variable to js Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

In my search controller I have an instance variable, `@results`. I set it to return a dummy result, `'foo'`.

In my search.html.erb view... I set window.results = `<%= raw @results.to_json %>`.

At the top of my search.js asset file, I `console.log(results)` and get `undefined`, but when I get into the devtools after the page load, results is populated with `'foo'`. The console.log statement is also wrapped in a jquery ready function.

What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails assets are precompiled so they don't have access to instance variables coming from the controller. Embed the Javascript directly into your view using a `script` tag and access the `@results` just like you did. You could also initiate a call to an external Javascript file.

Comment: That's my case too, but I want to have the same JS in multiple views (not everywhere). When I put my JS in an external file, the ERB doesn't evaluate. Any ideas?